# Type casting issue in C# and wcf header in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am now developing a WCF service using visual studio 2013 . My service contains a custom header field must be passed. Field name is `"lisenseKey"` I developed it. WCF service is working fine. Now I am about to call my service to test. I added a service reference to client project. Now I am calling like this:

```
MyService.Myservice proxy = new MyService.Myservice();
proxy.LisenseKey = "xxxxxx";
Label1.Text = proxy.GetMessage(TextBox1.Text);
```

When I assign license key value like this, it is showing error with red underline that:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type string to MyService.MyService.string"

How can I type cast in this condition? Or is there any way to pass header? And I do not know how to use `"MessageHeader"`.

Comment: Could you post the code for your service?

Comment: This is my service code . Please can anyone help me . I am just trying to consume "GetMessage" service

Answer (score 0):

Here is my service code . I am just trying to consume "GetMessage" method .

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyservice
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void DoWork();

        [OperationContract]
        string GetMessage(string name);
    }

    public class MyServiceMessageInspector:System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request,System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel,
            System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            if(request.Headers.FindHeader("LisenseKey","")==-1)
            {
                throw new FaultException("Lisense Key Was Not Provided");
            }

            var lisenseKey = request.Headers.GetHeader<string>("LisenseKey", "");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lisenseKey))
            {
                throw new FaultException("Lisnse key is not valid");
            }

            if(lisenseKey!="12345x")
            {
                throw new FaultException("Lisense key is not valid");
            }

            return instanceContext;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply,object correlationState)
        {

        }
    }

    public class MyServiceMessageInspectorBehaviour:Attribute,System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription serviceDescription,
            System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase,
            System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint> endpoints,
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {

        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription serviceDescription,
            System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
            foreach(ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
            {
                foreach(var endpointDispatcher in channelDispatcher.Endpoints)
                {
                    endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new MyServiceMessageInspector());
                }
            }
        }

        public void Validate(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription serviceDescription,System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {

        }
    }
```